# How to render parent components after rendering of child components in Angular is complete

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently developing a page with the following layout using Angular.

[image]

The problem is to show the parent component when all the sub-components of the parent component are rendered.
The reason is that the length of all sub-components is dynamic, so layout changes occur a lot.
(It is difficult to change the skeleton or design.)

However, when the parent's `*ngIf` is false, the parent component cannot be rendered because the event that occurs at the time of rendering completion of the sub-components does not occur.
I want to know how to solve this situation.

Below is a brief summary of my code.
I'm a beginner developer who's not familiar with Angular. I really want to solve this problem, so please give me a lot of opinions.

```
// parent component template
<parent-component *ngIf="isAllChildLoaded">
 <childA (onLoad)="updateLoadState($event, 'childA')"/>
 <childB (onLoad)="updateLoadState($event, 'childB')"/>
 <childC (onLoad)="updateLoadState($event, 'childC)"/>
</parent-component>


// parent component ts

childALoaded = false;
childBLoaded = false;
childCLoaded = false;

get isAllChildLoaded() {
 return childALoaded && childBLoaded && childCLoaded
}

updateLoadState(event: boolean, type: string) {
  if (type === 'childA') this.childALoaded = true;
  if (type === 'childB') this.childBLoaded = true;
  if (type === 'childC') this.childCLoaded = true;
}


// all child component ts
@Output()
onLoad = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.onLoad.emit(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking on stackblitz, it seems the parent `ngAfterViewInit` is trigerred after all the children `ngAfterViewInit` are trigerred, so you can simply add the logic in the `ngAfterViewInit` of the parent!

[image]

[`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-smb62j)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what I want is to decide whether to render the parent component with ngIf.  When an event occurs after loading data on all child components, I tried to render the variable that determines whether the parent component should be rendered true, but I found that the life cycle method of the child component did not work while the parent component was not rendered by ngIf. Is there any other good way to solve this problem?

Comment: @haaaam When you use ngIf the component and its children will not get rendered so using ngIf is the wrong solution, instead use the hidden attribute [hidden]="someVariable" will render the children and hide the parent also!